# Custom Edit distance weights for operations in Lucene FuzzySearch

Tags: java, search, lucene, search-engine, fuzzy-search

I came across this python library https://pypi.org/project/weighted-levenshtein/ which allows to specify different costs/weights for different operations(insertion, substitution, deletion and transposition) which is very helpful in detecting and correcting keystroke errors.

I have been searching through lucene library [FuzzySearch](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) which uses Damerau-Levenstein distance to check if something like this is supported to specify different costs/weights for different operations but not able to find any.

Please let me know if there exists a way to specify our custom costs/weights within Lucene Fuzzy-Search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you would have to extend and/or edit lucene code.  To support fuzzy matching, lucene compiles an `Automaton` using the `LevenshteinAutomata` class, which implements [this algorithm](https://dmice.ohsu.edu/bedricks/courses/cs655/pdf/readings/2002_Schulz.pdf), and not only doesn't support edit weights, but only supports matching for up to 0 to 2 edits.

How one might edit this algorithm to produce an automaton that supports weighted edits is beyond my knowledge, but could be worth a try as it would make your customization simple (would only have to override the [`getAutomaton`](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/54fba99cb131c7414caf2c21b52aa990ac17db3e/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.java#L171) method) and would (theoretically) keep performance consistent.

The alternative would be to forgo the idea of an automaton to support fuzzy matching and simply implement a weighted levenshtein algorithm, like the one you have linked to, directly in the [actual fuzzy match check](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/d5d6dc079395c47cd6d12dcce3bcfdd2c7d9dc63/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyTermsEnum.java#L275).  By doing this, however, you could pay a rather high performance cost depending on the nature of the fuzzy queries you handle and the content of your index.

Comment: As an alternative, are you suggesting that instead of dealing with automata rather implement the weighted levenshtein in an algorithmic way?